# Sexism in survey

Tags: discussion, feedback, stack-overflow-developer-survey

["How likely is it that a recommendation you make will be acted upon?"](https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/StackOverflowSurvey)

One of the responses is:
"I am the man" [I am the head honcho]

Maybe I'm the woman making decisions?

Comment: I like the informal way those answers are worded, and I find "sexism" a gross exaggeration, but it's hard to deny the OP has a point.

Comment: "Sexism" is a gross exaggeration? | sex·ism [sek-siz-uhm] –noun
1. attitudes or behavior based on traditional stereotypes of sexual roles. | If assuming the boss is a "man" isn't sexism, I don't know what is.

Comment: @Sijae I agree it should be changed. But "I am the man" / "You're the man" are established sayings with no implicit sexist meaning, and I'm pretty sure nothing malicious was intended. Which is why I find the label a bit too strong.

Comment: I find it weird that the survey doesn't include "Server programmer" which is probably in the top.. I'm sure there are many many more server programmers than kernel driver developers.

Comment: @Kop yeah and (I think you were the one who pointed that out in the chat?) Java is missing in the list of languages. Yay!

Comment: @Pekka:  When's the last time you said "You're the man" to a woman?  I know a few women who would take great offense, regardless of how you meant that.

Comment: @Pekka: it wasn't me =p

Comment: @GreenMatt to repeat: **I agree it should be changed** because it excludes women. I just don't agree with the OP's harsh classification.

Comment: Anyway, what we need is an alternative that is as cool as "I'm the man!" Any suggestions?

Comment: I know a couple of women who say *"I'm the man."* when things they had to fight for go the way they claimed. It's idomatic.

Comment: IMHO this is just PC overkill - If the intent wasn't discrimination/insult/derogation, why take offence?

Comment: @Pekka, perhaps the OP could've phrased it differently. I interpreted Sijae's title as "this phrase is sexist", not that Jeff/the survey's author/SO in general is sexist. Regardless, for those of us who consider ourselves feminists, it's often difficult to separate these issues because we may frequently encounter men who are quite progressive, excepting in cases where women are involved.

Comment: It's a figure of speech, that like a lot of generic speech in English applies either way.

Comment: @Pekka: That's mighty white of you to take such a balanced line in this comment thread, but not all established sayings are free of prejudice.

Comment: @Charles your point being? That people need to be reprimanded for using "I'm the man!"?

Comment: @Pekka: No, just that it is not gender neutral, and so you should be sensitive when using it.  Wodehouse uses "very white of you" and it is funny and not racist.  Wesley Snipes used it, and made an anti-racist point.  When Edith Wharton's Elmer Moffat character says it, he comes across ... not the way she intended.

Comment: @Charles I don't know Edith Wharton but I think I see what you mean. But I never said it is gender neutral, or that you shouldn't be sensitive when using it - as said, I can see this choice doesn't work at all for a woman answering the survey. What I always meant to say is, change it and move on.

Comment: @Pekka: I actually meant to flag dmckee with my original comment.  Oops, sorry.

Comment: It's just not sexist. To overstate the significance of such a petty issue as colloquialism is to undermine feminism. You're not demanding equal rights, you're demanding androgyny. I find this behaviour absolutely infuriating.

Comment: It is androgyny, since women and men can be bosses. The phrase exists because of traditional male power. You can push for its change. And don't worry, feminists can still enact their larger goals -- "petty" semantics won't wear them out.

Comment: Come on _guys_ ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alternative suggestions:

- I am the boss
- My word is law
- I call the shots
- What I say gets done
- I run this place

Comment: My vote for *I call the shots*, also might add *I run this place*

Comment: @Goran nice! Added

Comment: I vote for "I'm the bowess"

Comment: Who is the walrus?

Comment: Above being the boss: I'm the [baws](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NisCkxU544c). Needs to happen now.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks everyone for your feedback. As the writer of the survey, I apologize if the response in question was seen as androcentric - this was certainly not my intent.

I've taken the suggestions seriously and made the appropriate changes to the survey. I chose to change this response to "I run this place". I also added "Java" as a language choice and "Server Programmer" as an occupation choice.

Comment: +1 for the updates, and I hope no one takes offense, but I can't help pointing out the irony wherein one woman raised issue with what she felt was sexist wording in a survey written by *another woman*. =D

Answer (score 6):

I agree with you on that it should be changed.

But then, should we change all already established phrases?
If "I'm the man" implies that the boss should be male, then doesn't it mean that "No man's land" belongs to women... Well, I'd like to see confused faces of all these cowboys :)

Unfortunately, in many languages words "man" and "human" are treated like synonyms, and English is no exception.

Anyway, calling it sexist is correct. But, I don't think anyone meant it to be offensive.. These are just leftovers from history.

Answer (score 4):

No, it shouldn't be changed.

It's a colloquial expression.  That's no more sexist than to hear,

> Hell hath no fury like a woman scorned

What, men can't have fury? They can't be scorned?

Comment: The fact that some jobs/phrases/etc assume that the person is a woman doesn't make it right; wrong + wrong != right.

Comment: This just shows the extent of the sexism in yourself and our culture.  It is sexist and the fact that you hear it a lot does not make it less so.

Comment: There are many, *many* phrases with racist/sexist/xenophobic origins, whose origins most people have long since forgotten about.  No need to make George our whipping boy for suggesting that realizing current speakers mean no offense and moving on might be more practical than attempting to rewrite the English language.  Suggesting changing the wording is fine, but no need to accuse the survey writers of bigotry.